# Apache rewrite rules for creating user friendly urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am relatively new to rewrite and cant get the following to work. (clearly my domain is not testsite, but dont want my proper one going public as its not finished yet.)

i want to rewrite testsite/fishing/region/region.php?region=fife

to:

testsite/fishing/fife.php

then want to rewrite testsite/fishing/region/fishery/fishery.php?url=goldenloch

to

testsite/fishing/fife/goldenloch.php

I am using the following rules

```
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)\.php$ /fishing/region/region.php?region=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /fishing/region/fishery/fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
```

each rule works on its own but when combined only the last one work. I have added the [L] flag which i believe should stop any other rewrite rules of the condition is met. however this still doesnt work.

Comment: Doesn't look like that first rewrite line will match either of the urls. And the second rewrite line will only match the first url.

Comment: how come? the first rule should match and produce fishing/fife.php ?

any corrections would be helpful :)

Comment: Never mind my comment, I got confused in the direction you want the rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i needed to do

```
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]*) fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*) region.php?region=$1 [L]
```

with the longer query first and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seemed to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/fishing/([^/]*)\.php$ /fishing/region/region.php?region=$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /fishing/region/fishery/fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [R,L]
```

The only difference  from yours (I think) is the leading `/` and I used redirects (`R`) just to see it was working. You should be able to remove the `R` so the user doesn't see the real url in his browser.

Just in case you're not, I would recommend using a command line tool (like `curl`) and not a browser to test this, just so you avoid any caching or other annoyances:

```
curl -vv 'http://localhost/fishing/fife/goldenloch.php'
```

You'll see the `Location` header in the server's response, that's the redirect at work. In my case, I see:

```
Location: http://localhost/fishing/region/region.php?region=fife
```

and

```
Location: http://localhost/fishing/region/fishery/fishery.php?url=goldenloch&region=fife
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work.. /fishing/fife.php goes to 404 .htaccess is placed in the websites root only.. could this be causing problems?

The requested URL /fishing/fife/goldenloch.php was not found on this server.

althought region.php is in the correct place (fishing/region/region.php)

also /fishing/region/region.php?region=fife works fine.

Comment: Definitely the .htaccess might be the problem. Try putting the conf in the main apache httpd.conf and see if it works there. If so, then you need to set `AllowOverride`, like `AllowOverride All` in your <Directory> if you really want to use an .htaccess file.

Comment: if i place only one of the rules in the .htaccess file then it works fine. its when i place them both in the file that only the later one works. puting the / infront of fishing makes neither of them work at all.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'd look at `RewriteLogLevel` at this point, maybe the logs will help you troubleshoot. Good luck.

Comment: my logs for april is over 4mb and is 1678 pages with over 230,000 words. Dont even have a clue where to begin looking. My rewrite conditions dont seem that complicated comapred with others i have seen. I bet that there is a small mistake somewhere and i would be very grateful if someone could help to point out such mistake(s) or provide an alternative working solution. Thanks for you help anyway Steve